# Update section in Varchar(max) SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a `varchar(max)` field that i use as a ini file.

My problem is i need to update part of the field but i do not know the full value that i want to replace.

```
E.G.
    NewBook=N
    SaveFolderName=C:\temp

I want to update to be 
    NewBook=Y
    SaveFolderName=INSERT PATH HERE
```

Comment: `varchar(max)` let's me think, this is for SQL Server. I added the tag. Please change to the tag of the DBMS you're actually using, if my assumption was wrong.

Comment: You need to look at string parsing. When you need to update, pull back the existing full value from SQL, then do some string parsing of the value to update the full value, then update in SQL

Comment: Perhaps `REPLACE` is what you are looking for: `UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET YourColumn = REPLACE(REPLACE(YourColumn, 'NewBook=N', 'NewBook=Y'), 'SaveFolderName=C:\temp', 'SaveFolderName=INSERT PATH HERE')
WHERE YourTableID = 1;`